# Как посчитать количество связей в таблице?

Tags: sql, spring-data-jpa

У меня есть сущности **Event** и **User**.

User может голосовать за Event. Для отображения голосов я сделал таблицу связей **events_users**, которая содержит два FK:

```
event_id     user_id
```

Теперь я пытаюсь составить запрос, чтобы посчитать количество связей в этой таблице. А именно, я пытаюсь узнать, сколько голосов было у конкретного Event. Т.е. мне надо посчитать количество строк, в который event_id=id. Я пытаюсь составить запрос для `Spring DATAJPA`, но ничего не получается. Как мне правильно составить запрос?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так как **events_users** не содержит сущностей, то с этой таблицей не получится работать средствами JPQL. Для подсчёта количества записей в этой таблице в JpaRepository необходимо создать следующий метод:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT COUNT * FROM events_users WHERE event_id=:id", nativeQuery = true)
int votesCount(@Param("id") int id);
```